# Why boost converter burns with large output capacitor?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

In this circuit, the boost converter burns each time at start up and SW becomes connected to GND.

Then I just removed 10V , 220uF tantalum capacitor at the output and the problem solved.

In the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61022.pdf) of TPS61022 it said about minimum required output capacitor but it didn't say anything about maximum allowed output capacitor.

Why a large output capacitor causes the converter burn? Is it normal?

Is there any way to prevent it?

[image]

Comment: What burns? The IC or the inductor? If the IC, are you sure it's burnt and not just shut itself off due to over-current protection?

Comment: In any case, it sounds like an inrush current issue. You could either reduce the load capacitance, find some way to "turn on" the load capacitance gradually after power up, or find a converter IC with a slow-start feature.

Comment: Have you got the tantalum cap the correct way around?

Comment: @ThePhoton The IC burns. yes i checked it. the IC burns and after that draws a lot current due to the short circuit of SW to GND.

Comment: @Justme do you mean its polarity?I think all the things are right with capacitor. i also tried an electrolytic capacitor and still the IC burns.

Comment: strange. According to the datasheet it should soft start (7.3.2Enable and Soft Start)... did you check if the inductor is appropiate? What happens if you add additional caps to the power input as well? You could limit the current with a series resistor forming a low pass.

Comment: Is this your entire, exact schematic? Is this laid out on a well-thought-out PCB or is this on a breadboard?

Comment: @ChristianB. yes i tried some XAL6030-122MEB and SRP1245A-1R8M which are high-quality inductors and as i was suspicious to those i replaced them with a new one before checking the output capacitor

Comment: @AdamLawrence yes it's all my circuit and i use a pcb. i just copyed the recomended layout in datasheet

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: Datasheet does state maximum capacitance. It's 1000uF.

Comment: @Justme can you please address the part of datasheet which refered to maximum capacitance?

Comment: @DKNguyen yes but not an advanced one.

Comment: You could try adding a diode from the input to the output like the circuit on page 19 of the datasheet

Comment: @Pangus i tried this too but it didn't help.

Comment: Purely speculative, so just a comment.  The IC goes into bypass (pass transistor stays on) any time the input voltage is higher than the set output voltage.  The ripple on the output is proportional to the ESR of the output capacitor and the output current - high current, high ripple.  If the ripple gets high enough, I could imagine the output voltage being low enough to trigger the pass through.  Now your transistor has to conduct a high current longer than it is designed to do.  Try ceramic capacitors.

Comment: Note to other readers: FYI this question is related to the OP's previous question "[my boost converter burns](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/450649/my-boost-converter-burns)", with the same design. There, the problem seemed to be triggered by (it's a bit unclear, but seemed to be) adding an ammeter in the input supply with a 100 ohm burden resistance. It was during this investigation that removing the 220 uF output capacitor was reported to solve the problem with the boost converter burning, and so led to this new question. There might be useful info in that previous question.

Comment: @SamGibson yes at first i was suspected to the series resistor of ammeter but then i realized my problem is general and even without the ammeter still the IC burns.

Comment: also, I should mention that sometimes when I connected the battery it didn't burn and worked fine but after 3 or 4 times connecting and disconnecting the battery it would eventually burn. this behavior was misleading in the troubleshooting process. I burned about 15 TPS61022.
after removing 220uF capacitor I test the circuit a lot of time with no load and also 0.5A load conditions and connecting and disconnecting the battery about 100 times and all the things were right.

Comment: just now for being sure that the problem is exactly the output capacitor I put a new 220uF tantalum capacitor back and I burned another TPS61022. :)

Comment: @alireza Maximum capacitance is under Recommended Conditions on page 4. Also did you read the part about having only ceramic capacitors and long leads on input, causing ringing and instability, possibly leading to part damage?

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. It was put "on hold" in order to allow you to improve it before people try to answer it. Do not create a duplicate question.